# Combining arbitrary number of lists inside json

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6, iterator

I have some JSON where each key stores an array, and I need to combine all those arrays into a single array.  My current solution doesn't seem the most friendly to review, but without `forEach` not able to return a value i'm struggling for a succinct solution.

```
config = {"levels": {"first": ["a", "b", "c"], "second": ["d", "e", "f"]}};

let combine = [];
Object.keys(config["levels"]).forEach(key=>combine.push(config["levels"][key]));
let levels = [].concat.apply([], combine);
// levels == ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I never know how children `config["levels"]` will have there will be so this needs to be dynamic.

Comment: `const levels = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(config.levels));` will do it. BTW access object properties is much better using dot notation `config.levels.first` rather than bracket notation `config["levels"]["first"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First

> but without forEach not able to return a value i'm struggling for a succinct solution.

Addressing this in your post, in the future it may help to know you can use the [.map() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which *does* return values to an array, unlike `forEach()`

an example using .map() and what you have:

```js
const config = {"levels": {"first": ["a", "b", "c"], "second": ["d", "e", "f"]}};
const accessor = config.levels

let combine = Object.keys(accessor).map(key=>{return accessor[key]});
let levels = [].concat.apply([], combine);

console.log(levels);
// levels == ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

### More Succinct Solution

That said, something like this may be what you're looking for:

```js
const config = {"levels": {"first": ["a", "b", "c"], "second": ["d", "e", "f"]}};
const accessor = config.levels

const combine = Array.prototype.concat(...Object.values(accessor));
console.log(combine)
```

NOTE 1: Accessor is pulled out in case it needs to change, but is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

### Feedback

Is this code wrapped in a function? I ask because in the first line, i.e.

> ```
> config = {"levels": {"first": ["a", "b", "c"], "second": ["d", "e", "f"]}};
> ```

`config` is declared outside any brackets and without any keyword like `var`, `let` or `const`, which leads to it being declared globally. It is wise to avoid using global variables unless you are absolutely sure you have no other way to accomplish a task. This avoids scenarios like unintentional re-assignment and tight coupling.

Also, unless a variable is re-assigned, it is wise to use `const` instead of `let`. This will prevent unintentional re-assignment. `combine` could be declared with `const` since it is never re-assigned.

---

Whenever an array is declared and then added to via a loop (like `forEach`) you should consider using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method instead.

So the following lines

> ```
> let combine = [];
>  Object.keys(config["levels"]).forEach(key=>combine.push(config["levels"][key]));
> ```

Could be rewritten like this:

```
const combine = Object.keys(config["levels"]).map(key=>combine.push(config["levels"][key]));
```

Perhaps it would be helpful to go through [these functional JS exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/), where you practice implementing methods like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`.

---

As was mentioned in a comment, [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) can be used instead of bracket notation to accessing object properties. It is ["*faster to write and clearer to read*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/1575353)<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/1575353)</sup>

### A Simpler Technique

One simplification would be to use `Object.values()` to get the nested arrays, and then use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to join the arrays together.

```js
const config = {"levels": {"first": ["a", "b", "c"], "second": ["d", "e", "f"]}};
const levels = Object.values(config.levels).flat();
console.log("levels: ", levels);
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/1575353</sub>